# Sql that uses one table and gives an output of all possible combinations

Tags: sql

I have a table with the following information that I would like the output to be formatted with every combination. For each record there should be an instance of one other record next to it until it has gone through the complete file. What i want to do is use the 4 values to calculate a relationship between Vaue1 / Value2   and new Value1/ new Value2

```
id    Value1   value2    
100   34        48
101    35       45 
102   22       15 
103    35      17 
104   37       10
```

and the output should be

```
 100   34   48   101  35   45 
 100   34   48   102  22   15
 100   34   48   103  35   17
 100   34   48   104  37   10
 101   35   45   102  22   15
 101   35   45   103  35   17
 101   35   45   104  37   10
 102   22   15   103  35   17
 102   22   15   104  37   10
 103   22   15   104  37   10
```

As can been seen those are all the combinations of the sql table but i have thousands of these i want to do.

Will there be a sql query that i could get this formatting and going through the table making new rows on the output that are not duplicate.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join`:

```
select t1.id, t1.value1, t1.value2, t2.id, t2.value1, t2.value2
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.id < t2.id
order by t1.id, t2.id;
```